# Get user claims after federation authN and include it in requesting a JWT

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, ws-federation

I have an Owin based Web App and a backend Web API, they are authenticated against AAD and the workflow can be describe as below listed.

- Web App authenticates end users against AAD using Federation Authentication.
- Web App requests a JWT from AAD for accessing the backend Web API.

The main code for authenticating end users.

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // other code...
        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Wtrealm = realm,
            MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata
        });
    }
```

The main code for getting JWT for accessing the backend API:

```
    internal async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);


        var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(apiId, credential);
        // Here, what I wanted is to use the other overloaded method
        // authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(apiId, credential, userAssertion);
        // But to instantiate a UserAssertion instance, the only way is 
        // to use the constructor new UserAssertion(assertionString)
        // and the assertionString should be in JWT format
        // unfortunately, the assertionString from Ws-Federation auth is
        // for sure in SAML2 format. So, the question is: 
        // Give I am using Ws-Federation auth protocal, How can I pass the
        // user information in requesting a JWT to backend API resource?

        return result.AccessToken;
    }
```

Generally, the whole authentication workflow is OK, I can both authenticate end users and get JWT for accessing backedn APIs. But the problem is that there is no end user claims in the JWT. I am sure I should get users claims from the federation authentication result and then put them in the process of requesting the JWT. Unfortunately, with all methods, libraries and classes I didn't find a solution to do that.

BTW, https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect gives an example how to obtain a JWT with end user claims included, but the solution does not work with my scenario as I am using Federation authentication rather than OpenID Connect.

***Edit***

To make the question clear: in the web app, I would like to request a JWT token for accessing the backend web api by using the method `AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync`.

From my demo code, you can see I am using the `AcquireTokenAsync(apiId, clientCredential)` overloaded verion. But this version does not attach the end users claims inside. Actually what I needed is the `AcquireTokenAsync(apiId, clientCredential, userAssertion)` overloaded method.

However, to instantiate a `UserAssertion`, I need the user assertion string which is the `AccessToken` from user authentication result. Unfortunetaly, the `UserAssertion` class only accept JWT format assertion string, but the Ws-Federation authentication returns the SAML2 format assertion string, so I am not able to instantiate a `UserAssertion` instance.

So, my question is: given the condition that I am using Ws-Federation authentication protocol for authenticating an end user, in the backend how can I pass the user assertion information (it is in SAML2 format) to AAD for requesting a JWT for a backend api resource?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

AAD provides "canned" claims. There are no claims rules to add other attributes to the token.

Refer: [Supported Token and Claim Types](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-token-and-claims/).

If you want other attributes, you need to use the [Graph API](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/).

Comment: the question is not to "add" an attribute to the token, but is a question of how to pass the user claims (claims information is in either ClaimsPrincipal or SAML2 type assertion string from Ws-Federation authentication result) information in requesting a JWT token from AAD for accessing a backend Web API resource?  Please refer tho the *Edit* section in the original question for more information.